# How to Connect NodeJS App with a third party app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node js app which is running on localhost:3000. This app has all the CRUD functions which work with MySQL Database. Now I want to connect this app with another app which is running on another server let's say localhost:3001. Using second app, I want to call functions of first app and send and receive data from first app. How is this possible. Should I use some Web Socket or should I call those functions straight forward like this 
**localhost:3000/create_user**

Comment: They'll have to communicate through a network protocol of your choice. You can add a standard HTTP(s) API for that service to consume as well, or you can go with TCP comms. The answer is subjective and depends on the use case(s).

Comment: Ok Thanks. Can you give me some reference link? My use case is I want to add a user detail in database using third party app

Comment: You can't "call functions" from one "app" to another. They need to communicate over some protocol, like http/s or ws. You need to take a look at examples of how node(express) communicates with front-end. Here is one: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/

Comment: You can use a basic Express (NodeJS server framework) server with a single API endpoint for doing so. You declare a route, and a controller for it which parses the request and calls your CRUD function for storing that info in the database.

Comment: @i.brod I mean, you _can_ (RPC) but that's still technically done through networking of course.

Comment: yeah...but i doubt he means anything fancy like that :D